# What linguistic tools do you use?

Tags: resources, dictionary, thesaurus, vocabulary

I've got a [Flip Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1582971404), a Thesaurus, my trusty Strunk&White, and I use the almighty GOOG(le) should I ever be unsure of the definition of a word. What does everyone else use? Is there some handy reference that I'm missing?

I'm not really concerned with style books...I see we've got two threads on those already. I want to know about word references and such.

Answer (score 5):

I like to use the book "The Synonym Finder," though it is rather bulky to have lying around.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/), [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/), [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/), Google Dictionary. And Google search as well.

Answer (score 1):

I find the [Oxford Collocations Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0194325385) very useful. It tells you which verbs tend to be used with a specific noun, which adverbs tend to be used with a verb, etc.

For non-native speakers this a real treasure which is unfortunately little known. Collocations are the kind of intuitions about a language which are very difficult to fully acquire, and they are hard to fathom from a normal dictionary.

I believe - though it's not really for me to say - that it also has a value for native speakers, both as useful form of a thesaurus - and, for creative writes, as a sort of dictionary of cliches to be used with care.

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I mostly stick to dictionary.com (and the app version from my iPod) for most of my look ups. I also use Google for any words my spellchecker chokes on. 9 times out of 10 it will suggest the correct spelling, even if I give it something a bit off the wall.

Answer (score 0):

My window manager, Xfce, has a handy little taskbar app that will query a configurable list of dictionaries, thesauri, and other references -- everything from the Jargon File (a hacker lexicon) to Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary to Moby's Thesaurus, The CIA World Factbook, a legal dictionary, and dozens of other sources (you can also add custom ones).

It doesn't seem to have a name, just "Dictionary"

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary on Mac. Has a dictionary, thesaurus, and built-in formatted Wikipedia browser. I can switch between the definition of a word, the thesaurus, and the wikipedia entry for the word within immediately using keyboard-shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Visual Dictionaries.

These are good ones I'm familiar with

- **DK Illustrated Oxford Dictionary** and **Facts on File**, thanks to Writers SE, see https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/4639/2358
- **Merriam-Webster Visual Dictionary**, online and books, see https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/4623/2358.